# How to open .EML files on iPad

Tags: ipad

As an iPad users sometimes I need to open .msg and .eml files. Sometimes email files types come as attachments in email messages. How do I open such type of mail in my ipad?

Answer (score 1):

Email file viewer app from Kupon B.G known as Klammer. That is available in Apple's App Store. It will open Outlook .msg files, standard .eml files, and also winmail.dat files on your iPad.

First open email using the iPad's Mail application.  The file attachments were immediately visible in the email.

To view the file attachments just simply touched the .eml file we wanted to view, pressing on it for a full two seconds.  iPad then opened a window asking us which application we wanted to use to open the file.  then choose Klammer

It will view .eml file immediately appeared rendered in full html formatting.
It is a very simple app  for opening .msg and .eml email messages.

Klammer is no longer a free app, it is now $0.99 USD.

Comment: Is is freeware?

Comment: Yes it is absolutely free.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Klammer app I've had on my phone a long time, is no longer supported under IOS 11. It appears that the developer is no longer supporting it.

Answer (score -2):

If you just have a couple of  .eml files and you don't want to install software, there is a website called MessageViewer Online that will decode your .eml files and let you read the contents in your web browser. You can find it at http://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer/

Comment: How can somebody using an iPad get this to work?